# Materialize View Refresh in future

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I want to create Materialized view which will refresh Immediately and will refresh on every 3rd of each month i.e. June 3, July 3 etc.

Sysdate - 11th May

Also can we specify multiple table is refresh dependent function if MV is dependent on multiple table which are not loaded sequentially.

I am looking for suitable values in below clause.

```
 REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND START WITH ------- NEXT -----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Scheduler to execute a procedure that calls `DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH` procedure. Set the repeat_interval to :

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE (
   ...
  repeat_interval   => 'FREQ=MONTHLY; BYMONTHDAY=3',
  ...);
END;
/
```